# gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.env'

Tags: laravel, docker, google-app-engine, build, bitbucket

I have recently switched over my Laravel application from the GAE flex environment to the Standard environment, my builds were working quite well prior however now when I run the automated deploy script from Bitbucket I get the error

'gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.env''

Howevver my build is done through the DEVapp.yaml file and does not require a .env file, nor did it in the past. I am not entirely sure what may have caused this error though all believed to be associated files are included;

DEVapp.yaml

```
runtime: php72  # language of the app
# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
runtime_config:
  document_root: public
env_variables:
  #Put production environment variables here.
  APP_ENV: production   # or production
  APP_DEBUG : true # or false
  APP_KEY: xxxxxxxxx
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
#go to generate app key paragraf in this tutorial
  SESSION_DRIVER : cookie
  APP_TIMEZONE: UTC
# follow the part of the tutorial on setting up your SQL database
  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_DATABASE: xxxxxxxxx
  DB_USERNAME: xxxxxxxxx
  DB_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxx
  DB_SOCKET: xxxxxxxxx
  MAIL_DRIVER: xxxxxxxxx
  MAILJET_APIKEY: xxxxxxxxx
  MAILJET_APISECRET: xxxxxxxxx
  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: xxxxxxxxx
  MAIL_FROM_NAME: xxxxxxxxx
beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: xxxxxxxxx
```

Build Pipeline

````
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
# run composer check-platform-reqs for a list of required extensions.
image: php:7.2-fpm
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Test
        caches:
          - composer
        artifacts:
          - storage/**
          - vendor/**
          - public/**
          - .env
        script:
          #Update Image
          - apt-get update

          #Install Zip
          - apt-get install -qy zlib1g-dev zip unzip
          - docker-php-ext-install zip

          #Install Git
          - apt-get install -qy git
          - apt-get install -qy curl

          #Install MySqlPDO
          - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

          #Install Crypt
          - apt-get install -qy libmcrypt-dev
          - yes | pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1

          #Install Composer Platform Reqs
          - docker-php-ext-install bcmath

          #Required GD extensions
          #- apt-get install -qy php7.2-gd
          #- docker-php-ext-install gd
          #- sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
          #- sudo apt-get install php7.2-xsl
          # Installing first the libraries necessary to configure and install gd
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
          # Now we can configure and install the extension
          - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
          - docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

          #Copy Environment File
          - ln -f -s .env.pipelines .env

          #Install Composer
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install

          #Migrate Database
          #- php artisan key:generate
          - php artisan migrate

          #Run Test Suite
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose
        services:
          #Add MySql Database
          - mysql
# Additional Manual Step for Deployer if Needed.
# Otherwise move "artisan deploy..." to testing step so deployment is automatic.

#STAGING DEPLOYMENT SCRIPT
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Staging
        deployment: staging
        trigger: manual
        script:
          #Update Image
          - apt-get update
           #Install Zip
          - apt-get install -qy zlib1g-dev zip unzip
          - docker-php-ext-install zip

          #Install Git
          - apt-get install -qy git
          - apt-get install -qy curl

          #Install MySql
          #- apt-get install -qy mysql-client
          - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

          #Install Crypt
          - apt-get install -qy libmcrypt-dev
          - yes | pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1

          #Install Composer Platform Reqs
          - docker-php-ext-install bcmath

          #Required GD extensions
          #- apt-get install -qy php7.2-gd
          #- docker-php-ext-install gd
          #- sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
          #- sudo apt-get install php7.2-xsl
          # Installing first the libraries necessary to configure and install gd
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
          # Now we can configure and install the extension
          - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
          - docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

          #Copy Environment File
          - ln -f -s .env.pipelines .env

          #Install Composer
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install

          # Install Google Cloud SDK
          - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
          # Google Cloud SDK is pinned for build reliability. Bump if the SDK complains about deprecation.
          - SDK_VERSION=127.0.0
          - SDK_FILENAME=google-cloud-sdk-${SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
          - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${SDK_FILENAME}
          - tar -zxvf ${SDK_FILENAME} --directory ${HOME}
          - export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin

          - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.5.1
            variables:
                  KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE_DEV
                  PROJECT: $PROJECT_DEV
                  DEPLOYABLES: 'DEVapp.yaml'  ```
````

Comment: You have multiple references to `.env` in your pipeline config. Did you remove a build step you had for the flex env (maybe a custom runtime dockerfile)?

Comment: The pipeline works completely fine though it is when I change the lines;
runtime: {php}->{php72}, and remove environment and skip files (ive also completely removed the skip files and replaced it with the older reg ex system and the .gcloudignore, with no success)

Comment: Did you change anything within your build pipeline yaml file after switching from flex to standard? I was able to find an issue that may be related to yours, and it has to do of the way you declare the artifacts - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/opt-atlassian-pipelines-agent-build-does-not-exist/qaq-p/620478